# Angular 4 - Login Form

Tags: forms, angular

I have a login form as such:

```
 <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login();" novalidate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> Username: </td>
                <td> <input type="text" formControlName="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Password: </td>
                <td> <input type="password" formControlName="password"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> <button type="submit" [disabled]="loginForm.pristine" md-raised-button>Login</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</form>
```

On the submit button, I have [disabled]="loginForm.pristine". But when I type something in either of the input field and backspace to delete everything, it loses it's "pristine" status. How do I handle this?

Comment: What's your goal? Force the user to enter a user nale and a password? If so, make the two fields required, and disable the form if it is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the official docs,

> "pristine" means the user hasn't changed the value since it was
>   displayed in this form

Once you start interacting with the form, you loses the "pristine" status. It doesn't matter even if you delete what you type.

I think it would be better to check if the form is valid and disable the button if not.

You can do it like this

```
 <td> <button type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" md-raised-button>Login</button></td>
```